# No module name 'rosgraph' error when i try to run a simulation in ros2

Tags: ros2, gazebo-simu, urdf

```
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, Command
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch_ros.actions import Node

import xacro


def generate_launch_description():

    # Check if we're told to use sim time
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')
    use_ros2_control = LaunchConfiguration('use_ros2_control')

    # Process the URDF file
    pkg_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('my_bot'))
    xacro_file = os.path.join(pkg_path,'description','robot.urdf.xacro')
    # robot_description_config = xacro.process_file(xacro_file).toxml()
    robot_description_config = Command(['xacro ', xacro_file, ' use_ros2_control:=', use_ros2_control])
    
    # Create a robot_state_publisher node
    params = {'robot_description': robot_description_config, 'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}
    node_robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[params]
    )


    # Launch!
    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_sim_time',
            default_value='false',
            description='Use sim time if true'),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_ros2_control',
            default_value='true',
            description='Use ros2_control if true'),

        node_robot_state_publisher
    ])
```

**ros2 launch my_bot launch_sim.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/dango/.ros/log/2023-07-19-14-42-09-623059-dango-13036
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): executed command failed. Command: xacro /home/dango/Desktop/dev_ws/install/my_bot/share/my_bot/description/robot.urdf.xacro use_ros2_control:=true
Captured stderr output: warning: No module named 'rosgraph'
Usage: xacro [options] 
xacro: error: expected exactly one input file as argument**

This is the error message that I am getting

Comment: can you show your package.xml and setup.py files?